# Content length is not printed

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to print all headers to check my request but unfortunately it prints all headers expect content-length why it doesn't print content length ? what the problem is ? here is my request

```
public static String performPostCall(String requestURL,
        String postDataParams, int length, PrintWriter pw) throws Exception {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",
                "http://tempuri.org/SendRequest");
        conn.setRequestProperty(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length));

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        pw.println("Post request: " + url);
        for (String header : conn.getRequestProperties().keySet()) {
            if (header != null) {
                for (String value : conn.getRequestProperties().get(header)) {
                    System.out.println(header + ":" + value);
                }
            }
        }
        pw.println(postDataParams);
    //code..

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Try checking it after you post the request, and have received the response, or the response code. You're just checking it too soon. But don't expect it to be set to the value you provided. It is set automatically by Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe **Content-Length** is a header property that is automatically set based on the size of your request.

Comment: You're correct about the request header, but the methods you mention return the length of the [*response*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength--).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll remove those methods from my answer. I'll also check if there's a way to get the content length of the request set automatically.

Comment: As I already said, you are already correct about that. No need to check again.